# Store a timer value in a database? c#

Tags: c#, sql, timer

I have a global variable which is set up for the timer, "I", the program I'm creating has a user play a game level and store their level time in a database with other users. This is what I have already.

```
public static class Global
{
    public static int I = 0; 
}
```

^ this is the global variable for the timer.

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Adam\Documents\Data2.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"); 
        SqlDataAdapter sad = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count(*) From Login where Username= '" + txtUsername.Text + "' and Password='" + txtPassword.Text + "'", con); 
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO HighScore (Username, Score) VALUES(@Username,@Score)", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable(); //empty table
        sad.Fill(dt); 
        if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")   
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USERNAME", txtUsername.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Score", Global.I);
        }
        else // else it will display this error
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter the correct login details");
        }
```

^^ this is the code for the end screen of the game, as you can see i've tried taking the Global.I and addwithvalue @Score which is in the HighScore table in my database.
Now when i click the button it doesn't write anything to the database but I don't get any errors when i try and save, this is why i'm confused.
Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Just want to make you aware that data adapters etc. are extremely obsolete technology. You probably should use Entity Framework.

Comment: Regarding the actual question: Are you actually executing the command? Post that code, place a breakpoint on that line and make sure the line is even hit.

Comment: Nah, its okay. But you really should execute the queries you write.  That always helps.

Comment: You didn't open your connection before trying to fill the datatable. Add a `con.Open();` before the fill.

Comment: @Will I tried but it won't write to the database still :/

Comment: @Sylverac I tried but it won't write still

Comment: @AdamHardie can you post the error message you are getting and what line the compiler says is causing the error?

Comment: @Sylverac no man its okay but thank you, apomene answer fixed it for me :) thank you for helping thought

Comment: @AdamHardie which is the advice I already offered you. ;) Glad your problem is resolved though. Happy coding!

Comment: @Sylverac Yes I know :) I'm just learning so i wasn't sure how to do what you meant, have a good day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before executing any command you first must open the connection. You are opening the connection after calling `Fill()`!!. You will also have to execute `cmd`. Try:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Adam\Documents\Data2.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"); 
SqlDataAdapter sad = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count(*) From Login where Username= '" + txtUsername.Text + "' and Password='" + txtPassword.Text + "'", con); 

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO HighScore (Username, Score) VALUES(@Username,@Score)", con);
con.Open();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USERNAME", txtUsername.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Score", Global.I);
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); //empty table
sad.Fill(dt);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

It is also admirable that you know how to correctly use parameters,  however you use them only in 1 case instead of both queries.